# PowerShell to query nested child element of hashtable

Tags: powershell, nested, hashtable, where-object

In PowerShell, I want to get a count of all sports that use balls.  The challenge is that they're a level lower than I can access with a direct Where-Object query.  Here's the hashtable:

```
$league = @{
   school = @{
      name = 'Lincoln High School' 
      levels = ('9','10','11','12')
      } 
   sports = @{
      football = @{ 
         coed = 'b'
         season = 'fall'
         balls = $true
      }
      hockey = @{ 
         coed = 'b'
         season = 'winter'
         balls = $false
      }
      lacrosse = @{ 
         coed = 'g'
         season = 'spring'
         balls = $true
      }
      swim = @{ 
         coed = 'c'
         season = 'winter'
         balls = $false
      }
   }
}
```

How do I fashion the query to skip to the `balls`?  Each sport is named differently at the *key* level, and wildcards don't seem to work.

```
( $league.sports | Where-Object { $_.[?].balls -eq $true } ).count
```

I need something to bridge to the child element of the sport.

Comment: Hashtables aren't enumarable by default, so you have to call on `.GetEnumerator()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `.where(..)`:

```
($league['sports'].GetEnumerator().Where{$_.Value.Balls}).Count
```

Using `Where-Object`:

```
($league['sports'].GetEnumerator() | Where-Object {$_.Value.Balls}).Count
```

As you can see, both methods require the use of [`.GetEnumerator()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.getenumerator?view=net-6.0#system-collections-hashtable-getenumerator).

Another *more verbose* alternative:

```
$sports = $league['sports']
$sports.PSBase.Keys.Where{$sports[$_]['balls']}.Count
```